Projective modules over group rings and trace
Consider a finite extension of complete valued fields $L/K$ with corresponding extension of rings $B/A$. Suppose $L/K$ is Galois with group $G$. I want to show that $B$ is a projective $A[G]$ module iff $L/K$ is tamely ramified.
To this end I’ve been hinted at considering the trace map $\operatorname{Tr}\_{L/K}$. I know this map is surjective for tamely ramifies extensions as a map $B\to A$. I’m struggling to see how this allows us to deduce something about the structure of $B$ as an $A[G]$ module though. I can translate it to saying that the norm element $\sum_{\sigma\in G} [\sigma]$ acts on $B$ as a surjective map to $A$ but I don’t see where this ought to take me.
